# How can I theme the taxonomy/term/x page?

Tags: drupal, themes, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

Although it was easy to find some info online about how to theme other stuff (e.g. search results), it is impossible to find a straightforward article about how to theme the output of a taxonomy/term/247 page?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12):

In Drupal 6, you can make use of `node-taxonomy.tpl.php` and `page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php` files in your theme to template taxonomy pages considering that the second one is the wrapper for the first. Behave `node-taxonomy.tpl.php` like `node.tpl.php` and `page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php` like `page.tpl.php`. for example:

*page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php*

```
<?php require 'header.tpl.php'; ?>
    <body class="<?php echo $body_classes; ?>">
        <div id="page">
            <?php require 'page-navigation.tpl.php'; ?>
            <div id="main">
        <h2>Taxonomy term page</h2>
        <div class="taxonomy-content">
            <?php if ($tabs): echo '<div id="tabs-wrapper" class="clear-block">'; endif; ?>
            <?php if ($title && !$node): echo '<h2'. ($tabs ? ' class="with-tabs"' : '') .'>'. $title .'</h2>'; endif; ?>
            <?php if ($tabs): echo '<ul class="tabs primary">'. $tabs .'</ul></div>'; endif; ?>
            <?php if ($tabs2): echo '<ul class="tabs secondary">'. $tabs2 .'</ul>'; endif; ?>
            <?php if ($show_messages && $messages){ echo $messages; } ?>
            <?php echo $help; ?>
            <?php echo $content; // contains the output of node-taxonomy.php, that's why I call this wrapper template file. ?>
        </div> <!-- #taxonomy-content -->                   
            </div> <!-- #main -->           
        </div> <!-- #page -->
        <?php echo $closure; ?>
    </body>
<?php require 'page-footer.tpl.php'; ?>
```

*node-taxonomy.tpl.php*

```
<div id="node-<?php echo $node->nid; ?>" class="node<?php if($sticky) echo ' sticky'; ?><?php if(!$status) echo ' node-unpublished'; ?>">
  <div class="taxonomy-node">
      <div class="node-body">
        <a class="node-title" href="<?php echo $node_url ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>">
          <?php echo $title ?>
        </a>
        <span class="node-cck-field">
          <?php echo $node->field_cck_blah[0]['view']; ?>
        </span>                             
      </div>                
  </div>
</div>
```

Well, the most important part: By default the `node-taxonomy.tpl.php` is not known to Drupal, so we need to introduce this as a *template suggestion* in the our theme's `template.php` file, here we go:

```
/**
 * Adding custom PHPTemplate suggestions on taxanomy pages.
 *
 * @param $vars
 *   A sequential array of variables to pass to theme template.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy'){
    $suggestions = array('node-taxonomy');
    $vars['template_files'] = array_merge($vars['template_files'], $suggestions);
  }
}
```

Also there is a [`taxonomy-term.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7), regarding Drupal 7.
It's a code sample, dont' forget to use `check_plain()` & `check_url()` on printouts.

Comment: Thanks Sepehr! This works, but all of my views blocks on the page get the same formatting treatment... (they are displayed as node teasers) Is there a way stop from destroying my views?

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomy page is not magic in any that it requires something special to theme it. There's a template file, a preprocess function and some theming functions, much like any page.

If you would like to control the output of the default taxonomy page which is a bit raw, you can use views to overwrite the default page. You could then use views to only show node teasers, do some custom ordering, use a pager etc.

If you want to do something more specific you should edit your question to tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You better use following code in template.php

```
  foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-term-'. $term->tid;
  }
```

Because you can use file names such as node-term-YOUR-TERM-ID.tpl.php  for each term .

if you want to make it more efficient use :

```
  if ($hook == 'node') {
       if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') { 
        foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-term-'. $term->tid;
       }
    }
  } //if bracket close
```